# name for simple graph with loops

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a common name for simple graphs where additionally every vertex is allowed a single loop? These are graphs that correspond to symmetric 0/1 matrices, with 1's allowed on the diagonal, through their adjacency matrix.

For example I found a paper by Greenhill and McKay where they are called "loopy graphs", but only in the title.

Comment: I don't think there's a common name for these graphs.

Comment: I am not sure there is a name for these - but this is not my field. Even if there is, I doubt the language would be standard in that many people define a *simple* graph to have no multiple edges or loops, so that there could be no such object. But the closest I could find to what you were asking was a *reflexive graph*.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this hes no standard terminology. Reflexive would perhaps suggest that all vertices have a loop.